# how to read very big table from clickhouse to write it to hdfs using spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, clickhouse

Tell me, please, how to cut the table(clickhouse) to write it to hdfs
the table is large, more then 300 billion rows. I'm using spark(Scala).
I tried to select period(one month), it didn't work, I received error: **Caused by: java.io.EOFException: reached end of stream after reading 1572 bytes; 23242 bytes expected**

Comment: Are you using a JDBC driver?  Which one?  This seems like an error at that level.

Comment: hi! @Geoff Genz, there are my conf: val df = spark.read .format("jdbc").option("driver","cc.blynk.clickhouse.ClickHouseDriver").option("url", "jdbc:clickhouse://local/box") .option("user", "user").option("password", "pass") .option("dbtable", "table")

Answer (score 0):

The jdbc driver you are using doesn't appear to have been updated in 2 years and may no longer be compatible with recent ClickHouse versions.  I would suggest trying the officially supported ClickHouse Driver.

```
<groupId>com.clickhouse</groupId>
<artifactId>clickhouse-jdbc</artifactId>
<version>0.3.2-patch9</version>
```